# Why are my array's objects being destroyed on meteor insert?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

This might have to do with me updating Meteor this morning.

Anyway here is some code:

```
//this returns Words properly    
console.log('splitter', splitSentenceIntoWordsForward(sentence)) 

var wordsForward = splitSentenceIntoWordsForward(sentence)

 //if I remove this line then everything works.
UserSentences.insert({user: Meteor.userId(), words: wordsForward})

//If I don't remove the line above, this prints an array of empty objects like this: [ { }, { } ]
console.log("wordsForward new", wordsForward, JSON.stringify(wordsForward))
```

It appears that insert is destroying the objects in the array somehow.

My original code has been working for weeks. Only this morning has it stopped. (There are other things besides meteor update that could be involved. I have added simpleschema and collection2. I also change some publish methods, but this code is fully run on the server.

Here is more code:

```
UserSentences = new Mongo.Collection('userSentences')
Schemas.UserSentences = new SimpleSchema({
    words: {
        type: [Object],
        label: 'Words',
        optional: false
    },
    user: {
        type: String,
        label: 'user id',
        optional: false
    }
})
UserSentences.attachSchema(Schemas.UserSentences)

Meteor.methods({
    createArticle: function (text, title, share) {
        var article = {}
        var wordsArray = []
        article.title = title
        article.userID = Meteor.userId()
        article.text = text
        article.public = share
        var id = Articles.insert(article)
        article.paragraphs = []
        var paragraphs = splitArticleIntoParagraphs(text)
        console.log("paragraphs", paragraphs)
        paragraphs = paragraphs.filter(String)
        console.log('paragraphs w/o empties', paragraphs)
        _.each(paragraphs, function (paragraph, p) {
            // console.log("paragraph", paragraph)
            article.paragraphs[p] = {}
            article.paragraphs[p].read = false
            article.paragraphs[p].text = paragraph
            article.paragraphs[p].index = p
            // console.log("paragraphs[p]", article.paragraphs[p])
            var sentences = splitParagraphIntoSentences(paragraph)
            article.paragraphs[p].sentences = []
            _.each(sentences, function (sentence, s) {
                if (sentence !== "") {
                    article.paragraphs[p].sentences[s] = {}
                    // console.log("sentence", sentence)
                    article.paragraphs[p].sentences[s].text = sentence
                    article.paragraphs[p].sentences[s].read = false
                    // console.log("paragraphs[p].sentences[s]", article.paragraphs[p].sentences[s])
                    //console.log('splitter', splitSentenceIntoWordsForward(sentence))
                    var wordsForward = splitSentenceIntoWordsForward(sentence)
                    UserSentences.insert({user: Meteor.userId(), words: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(wordsForward))})
                    // console.log("wordsForward new", wordsForward, JSON.stringify(wordsForward))
                    article.paragraphs[p].sentences[s].forward = {}
                    article.paragraphs[p].sentences[s].forward.words = wordsForward
                    // console.log('wordsForward', JSON.stringify(wordsForward))
                    // var wordsReverse = splitSentenceIntoWordsReverse(sentence)
                    _.each(wordsForward, function (word, w) {
                        if (word) {
                            wordsArray.push(word._id)
                            // console.log('this word should split', word)
                            _.each(word.simplified.split(""), function (character) {
                                console.log(character)
                                wordsArray.push(Words.findOne({simplified: character})._id)
                            })
                            article.paragraphs[p].sentences[s].forward.words[w] = {}
                            article.paragraphs[p].sentences[s].forward.words[w].wordID = word._id
                            // article.paragraphs[p].sentences[s].forward.words[w].simplified = word.simplified
                            // article.paragraphs[p].sentences[s].forward.words[w].trad = word.trad
                            // console.log("word.simplified", word.simplified)
                            var characters = word.simplified.split('')
                            // console.log("characters", characters)
                            article.paragraphs[p].sentences[s].forward.words[w].characters = []
                            /**/
                            _.each(characters, function (character, c) {
                                if (character) {
                                    // console.log("character", character, p, s, w, c)
                                    article.paragraphs[p].sentences[s].forward.words[w].characters[c] = {}
                                    article.paragraphs[p].sentences[s].forward.words[w].characters[c].text = character
                                    article.paragraphs[p].sentences[s].forward.words[w].characters[c].wordID = Words.findOne({simplified: character})._id
                                }
                            })
                        }
                    })
                }
            })
        })
        console.log("done")
        article.words = wordsArray
        article.finishedCreating = true
        Articles.update({_id: id}, {
            $set: {
                paragraphs: article.paragraphs,
                words: wordsArray,
                finishedCreating: true
            }
        }, {bypassCollection2: true})
        return id
    }
})

var splitSentenceIntoWordsForward = function (string) { // DictionaryForwardMaximumMatchingOld
// console.log(new Date().toDateString())
    console.log('typeof', typeof string)
    var foundWordsArray = []
    var position = string.length
    while (position > 0) {
        // console.log("while")
        var index = position
        var partialString = string.slice(0, index)
        // console.log("partial sub: " + partialString.substring(0, 20))
        var found = Words.findOne({
            "simplified": partialString.substring(0, 20)
        })
        // console.log(partialString)
        if (found) {
            // console.log("found: " + found.simplified)
            // if (found.pinyin == "" && foundWordsArray.length > 1) { //punctuation at beginning of sentence isn't a wrapping concern.
            //     console.log("found punctuation")
            //     foundWordsArray[foundWordsArray.length - 1].simplified = foundWordsArray[foundWordsArray.length - 1].simplified + found.simplified
            // } else {
            foundWordsArray.push(found)
            console.log("found", found.simplified)
            // }
            position = position - 1
            var partialStringCount = partialString.length
            while (partialStringCount > 0) {
                // console.log("second while")
                string = string.substring(1)
                partialStringCount -= 1
            }
            position = string.length
            index = position
        }
        else if (partialString.length == 1) {
            var newEntryID = Words.insert({
                trad: partialString,
                simplified: partialString,
                pinyin: ""
            })
            foundWordsArray.push(Words.findOne({
                newEntryID
            }))
            var partialStringCount = partialString.length
            while (partialStringCount > 0) {
                string = string.slice(1, string.length) //remove first character
                partialStringCount -= 1
            }
            position = string.length
            index = position //advance(string.startIndex, position)
            console.log("added " + partialString)
        }
        else {
            // console.log("else")
            position = position - 1
            index = position
        }
    }
    //console.log("found: ", JSON.stringify(foundWordsArray))
    // console.log(new Date().toDateString())
    return foundWordsArray
}
```

Comment: Probably your changes to publish. You need to backtrack until it works again and work out where you introduced the problem

Comment: Does publish affect server side only code?

Comment: Here's what I know: you made changes to your app, and now it's not working. I don't know the context of when this code runs, so my suggestion is to backtrack and apply changes one by one until it breaks. Then you will know which change broke it. I have seen similar problems raised which end up being something to do with publish, so it's merely a hunch

Comment: What would make an insert do that? Also, what would make publish affect the server?

Comment: Can you show more of the code? `collection.insert()` cannot destroy its input args. I suspect a variable scoping issue.

Comment: More code added as requested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Collection2 was causing the problem.

This is how I got around it:

```
UserSentences.insert({user: Meteor.userId(), words: wordsForward},
                     {bypassCollection2: true})
```